# Two-dimensional bosonic field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, string-theory, field-theory, greens-functions

I'm struggeling with the following question:

> Consider a two-dimensional bosonic field theory defined by the following action
>   $$S =\frac{k}{2} \int dx_{1}dx_2 [(∂x_1  φ(x_1, x_2))^2 + (∂x_2 φ(x_1, x_2))^2
> ] $$
>   with a Green function
>   $$G(x) ≡  <φ(x_1, x_2)φ(0, 0)> = −\frac{1}{4\pi K} \ln(
> |x|^2),$$
>   $$x = (x_1, x_2).$$ 
>   Derive a quantum analogue of the Pythagoras theorem
>   $$: \cos(√4πKφ(x)) :^2 +: \sin(√4πKφ(x)) :^2
> =? $$
>   What happens when the arguments of cos and sin would have a different prefactor in front of φ(x) (e.g $\cos(\sqrt{\alpha\phi}$)
>   for some $\alpha\phi \neq \sqrt{4\pi K}$?

---

I defined the following vertex operator:

$V_{\alpha} = :e^{i\alpha \phi}:$

expanded the functions and I got:

$: \cos(√4πKφ(x)) :^2 +: \sin(√4πKφ(x)) :^2
=
\frac{1}{2}(:e^{i\alpha \phi}::e^{-i\alpha \phi}:+:e^{-i\alpha \phi}::e^{i\alpha \phi}:)$

But can I add these two normal ordered operators?

$\frac{1}{2}(:e^{i\alpha \phi}::e^{-i\alpha \phi}:+:e^{-i\alpha \phi}::e^{i\alpha \phi}:) = :e^{i\alpha \phi}::e^{-i\alpha \phi}:$

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Yes, you can. See (6.63)-(6.66) in di Francesco.